# Windows PowerShell: RemoveFileSystemItemIOError after loop

Tags: windows, powershell

I am a newbie with coding in Windows PowerShell.
So I have the below code to find max. width and height of jpg files in a subdir. After I found max values I cd to parent directory and need to delete the (temp) subdir.

But I can't do this, I get **RemoveFileSystemItemIOError**, and I am being told that all the jpg files in subdir are currently used by a different process. How do I solve/free them?

The code may be found below:

```
cd n;
$maxh=1;$maxw=1;
$(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg).FullName | ForEach-Object { 
$img = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_); 
if ($img.Width -ge $maxw) { $maxw=$img.Width}
if ($img.Height -ge $maxh) { $maxh=$img.Height}

}
cd ..;
rm n -r;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the image file using

```
$img = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_);
```

When you are done with it, you should run `$img.dispose()` otherwise Powershell will keep storing a reference to the image and prevent you from removing it.